# <body> inside Meteor package

Tags: meteor, package

I was trying to understand the Meteor accounts-ui-unstyled package and I was surprised to see that although the "main" template is the {{> loginButtons}}, because it is the one we include in our Webpage, there is one file in the package that contains a `<body>` tag that has some other templates inside it.
How does that work (two body tags in the same final webpage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quoting official Meteor full docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) :

> HTML files in a Meteor application are treated quite a bit differently
>   from a server-side framework. Meteor scans all the HTML files in your
>   directory for three top-level elements: `<head>`, `<body>`, and
>   `<template>`. The head and body sections are separately concatenated
>   into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on
>   initial page load.

Comment: Yes, I've read that too. And that's why this is strange; because this <body> in the package is not appearing in the webpage and is not behaving as supposed after reading Meteor docs...

Comment: I assume you're talking about this particular body tag : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons_dialogs.html#L1
These are all dialogs that won't get visible unless they are triggered by a specific action. You can search for these dialogs markup in your page body, they will be there but hidden by CSS.

Comment: That's right. But is there any advantage in doing that?